# Fixed: Console.log twice in the edit function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, block-editor, bug

Hi Guys I am using `$ npx @wordpress/create-block todo-list` package and I found something interesting. I have not changed everything in the file structure but my console.log or any variable get outputted twice.

**How to reproduce this problem?**

- Installing the @wordpress/create-block package
- Opening edit.js and adding `console.log("test")` above the render

My index and edit.js files

```
/**
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its behavior.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * All files containing `style` keyword are bundled together. The code used
 * gets applied both to the front of your site and to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Edit from './edit';
import save from './save';

/**
 * Every block starts by registering a new block type definition.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
registerBlockType( 'create-block/beta-toolbox', {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,
    attributes: {
        // New code added. Comment clarity
        imagedata: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [{image: "link1"},{image: "link1"},{image: "link1"}]
        }
    },

    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
} );
```

And the edit.js file

```
/**
 * Retrieves the translation of text.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-i18n/
 */
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

/**
 * React hook that is used to mark the block wrapper element.
 * It provides all the necessary props like the class name.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-block-editor/#useBlockProps
 */
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * Those files can contain any CSS code that gets applied to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './editor.scss';

/**
 * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the
 * editor. This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#edit
 *
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */

import {useEffect } from "@wordpress/element"
export default function Edit(props) {

console.log(props.attributes.imagedata);
// pushing the a new element to this array results to have adding it twice

    return (
        <p { ...useBlockProps() }>
            { __( 'Beta Toolbox – hello from the editor!', 'beta-toolbox' ) }
        </p>
    );
}
```

**Edit: By wrapping the code in an useEffect() hook it is solved**

Comment: I don’t believe this is a bug. This is just how React works. Is there a reason this is a problem?

Comment: I agree with you that this might be a functionality of React, but in this instance the outcome is undesirable. If I add a variable and try to change that, it gets changed twice instead of once.

Comment: That suggests to me that you’re setting the variable incorrectly. When creating React components, which the block editor is made of, you need to do things a certain way, but without an actual example if what you’re trying to do, it’s impossible to see what you’re doing wrong.

Comment: In my index.js i have attributes with a default value. It is an array of images (links). I read the value of the attributes inside the edit function because the props are written there. So in my other project I tried to add images to this array since the user is adding a new image. Like this console.log(), the array push is done twice. I have updated my post so you can see the example

Comment: @JacobPeattie I think I fixed it. I should've wrapped it in an useEffect hook!. I think i'm going to close this topic right now. But it was kind of annoying for me because it was the official package of Wordpress :)

Comment: Agreed - this is just React's default functionality. That `console.log()` will trigger each time the component renders. Normally we're doing things like pushing to an array attribute in a callback acting as an event handler, so the specific number of times a component renders is irrelevant. Initializing that value in a `useEffect()` isn't a bad idea - but if the uninitialized state is easily discernable, it would be more efficient to just do it in an `if( attributes.imagedata === undefined ) setAttributes( /* ... */ );` conditional.

Comment: @MienSao If you solved your issue you should post it as an answer.